# Vector representations for string with python

Tags: python, openai-api

I'm trying to create a script to get vector representations for string to avoid using [OpenAi embeddings](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/what-are-embeddings)
Can somebody advice how to do this using only python. For example I have a string 'Shoulder Pack' and after sending this string to python script I need to get back a list of numbers

```
[
    -0.006929283495992422,
    -0.005336422007530928,
    ...
    -4.547132266452536e-05,
    -0.024047505110502243
  ]
```

Comment: Search for opensource embedding libraries/models. And please see [ask]